# I have an iOS app in xamarin native, we are trying to integrate crashlytics

Tags: xamarin.ios

We need help to integrate the crashlytics in a xamarin iOS project.
We are trying to follow the below given steps, but we were unable to connect with the firebase console.

1. Installation of packages:  Xamarin.firebase.iOS.Crashlytics and Xamarin.firebase.iOS.Core
2. Downloaded the "GoogleService-Info.Plist"  file then added it in our project and set the build action as "Bundle Resource".
3. Build the project and run.

Please give a solution.

[image]

Comment: This guide maybe can help you https://alexduffell.wordpress.com/2018/06/26/using-crashlytics-with-xamarin-apps/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - You gave an example for Fabric crashlytics but we are looking for Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/03c7782cbc16d874e57ba01db31a6be8e6b8aa12/Firebase.Crashlytics/component/GettingStarted.md#add-firebase-to-your-app